# Extensive multi Calendar proiject using javascript [json/ajax]

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, calendar, fullcalendar

I have my calendar project as displayed below. I want to improve it using some tools. Is there any javascript code like `highcart.js` to use for calendar project? Such as dynamic, using tooltips and good design[image].

Comment: You can easily get jQuery or Angularjs framework's library for calendar but using only JavaScript..I doubt...

Comment: Check out http://fullcalendar.io/